# NativeScript Preview producing QR code, but not loading inside of app

Tags: nativescript, preview, nativescript-telerik-ui

Since yesterday, I have been trying to use Preview on the App I am currently working on and ran into an issue. The last time I touched the app was about 2-3 weeks ago and nothing has been changed since.

Issue:

1. **Using play.nativescript.org** - A QR code for the App gets generated (as expected), however scanning it, does not load the created app neither using iPhone nor Android. I reinstalled Playground and Preview on the phone, but nothing changed. I tried previewing one of the existing apps in market.nativescript.org and experienced the same issue.
2. **Using terminal on MacOS** - I used the last (same) version of the app on my laptop to preview it with `npm install -g nativescript@latest` and then `tns preview`. Same issue occurred here as well. The created app did not start in Preview.

Has anyone ran into this issue or has an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Having the same problem, can someone please assist. I just started on my playground, downloaded the app and I'm able to scan the barcode, makes a peep sound to confirm that is has been scanned, but doesn't close the barcode or open the app on my iPhone. If anyone is able to assist, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Adam are you using Kinvey somewhere in the app by any chance? 
In case you are, I ran into this issue in the end and fixing Kinvey (with approach 2. - Terminal locally) worken. Quite a few people managed to fix their issue the same way. 

https://github.com/NativeScript/playground-feedback/issues/190#issuecomment-678443301

If that doesn’t help, I am not sure, unfortunately. Do you see anything in the logs?

Comment: I am also adding the following link for reference, as my application is also in Angular. The issue is up until now still not resolved:
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/290

Comment: I was able to get it working by downloading both NativeScript apps from the App Store, instead of just the playground app. On Apple it doesn't;t give you feedback to download the other app whereas on Android, it gave me feedback to download the other app as well and so I did the same on Apple and got it to work, but thank you for your response.